# How to send the form data type request using Restkit

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

Data Format:

```
{
    "firstName": "arun",
    "lastName": "kumar",
    "contactInfo": {
        "email": "ak7896@gmail.com"
    },
    "password": "abcdefg"
}
```

Above is my request structure for sign up. Along with `data` key I have one more key for `profilepic` image named "main". Currently, I am using RestKit in my request dictionary I am creating is like below:

```
[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:self path:self.path_api parameters:@"data":@{                                                                       @"firstname":firstname, @"lastname":lastname, @"contactInfo": @{@"email":emailID}, @"password":pass}
                                                                            @"main": @{@"profileImage": profilePic? profilePic : nil}
```

but it throws me error 500. I think the dictionary which I am creating here is not correct.

Any suggestions would be really helpful for me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You haven't told us what is actually sent or what the server expects,new need to know both, and any other details the server returns in the error

Comment: { URL: myURL} { status code: 500, headers {
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Length" = 22;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Sun, 01 May 2016 16:54:55 GMT";
    Server = "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)";
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding,User-Agent";
    "X-Content-Type-Options" = nosniff;
    "X-Powered-By" = Express;
} }, NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 500}

Comment: How can i create above request structure with form data using restkit, i.e how can i create multiform request like my above request structure.

Comment: Your question shows JSON, not a form

Comment: data { "firstName": "arun", "lastName": "kumar", "contactInfo" : { "email": "ak7896@gmail.com"},"password": "abcdefg"}
main <image to upload>

*Note - above inputs are in form-data format where “data” & “main” are keys.

Comment: above is my request structure document.

Comment: `@{@"data":@{@"firstname":etc}, @"main":@{@"profileImage": etc}}`?

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary seems not well formatted , it should look like this

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:self path:self.path_api parameters:@{@"data":@{@"firstname":firstname, @"lastname":lastname, @"contactInfo": @{@"email":emailID}, @"password":pass}, @"main": @{@"profileImage": profilePic? profilePic : nil}}];
```

In case if data key isn't needed , it should be

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:self path:self.path_api parameters:@{@{@"firstname":firstname, @"lastname":lastname, @"contactInfo": @{@"email":emailID}, @"password":pass}, @"main": @{@"profileImage": profilePic? profilePic : nil}}];
```

Comment: My request is going like below:
request.body : @{                                                                        @"name":@{@"firstname":firstname, @"lastname":lastname}, @"contactInfo": @{@"email":emailID}, @"password":pass
  }
but on server side it is expecting data in form :
request.body.data : @{                                                                        @"name":@{@"firstname":firstname, @"lastname":lastname}, @"contactInfo": @{@"email":emailID}, @"password":pass
  }
now using form data i don't have any clue how to construct this requrest.

Comment: then u should use this method to send form data

`multipartFormRequestWithObject:method:path:parameters:constructingBodyWithBlock`

Comment: I am currently using the same but need to send request body as request.body.data where data is key for one of the form data dict.

Comment: have you checked documentation on github ? check this link 
https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit#post-an-object-with-a-file-attachment

Comment: already any form data are sent in body, you don't need to add your objects into body key